# reproduce same output with scikit-image resize and OpenCV resize function

Tags: python, opencv, keras, image-resizing, scikit-image

I'm trying to reproduce the same output with these snippets:

Scikit-Image + Keras

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize

image = resize(imread(img_path, as_grey=False), (80, 80), preserve_range=True, mode='constant')
image /= 255.
img_array = np.array([image])
pred_IN = model.predict(img_array)
```

OpenCV

```
import cv2

model = cv2.dnn.readNet('mynet.prototxt', 'mynet.caffemodel')
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
img = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=(1.0/255.0), size=(80, 80), swapRB=True, crop=False)
model.setInput(img)
pred = model.forward()
```

The problem is that I cannot get the same data to pass to the network (DNN module in case of OpenCV). Network is the same, input data is the same, but the results is slightly different and the reason is that resize function behaves differently between scikit-learn and OpenCV (used internally by blobFromImage) and don't know how to adapt the OpenCV code to match scikit-learn.
My final application will use OpenCV in C++, so I need to match this snippets, as my network has been trained with data generated by scikit-learn.

Comment: Are you using scikit-image resize function in first method?

Comment: Yes, first method is with scikit-learn resize function

Comment: Please include explicitly the relevant imports; is it really from `scikit-learn` or (as I guess) from `scikit-image`? Adjust the tags accordingly, if needed.

Comment: Sorry, it was scikit-image, edited

Comment: Have you tried using blobFromImage() just to read the data without resizing and then subsequently using cv2.resize() to adjust the size

Comment: I tried to resize before blobFromImage but result is the same.. it shoudn't change much as blobFromImage call internally cv2.resize. Can you point me to resize after blobFromImage ? I get a 4D array that I cannot use directly in cv2.resize.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is skimage use antialiasing (gaussian blur from `scipy.ndimage` before rescale) by default. You can achieve similar result wit resize in OpenCV by blurring your image (e.g. using `cv2.GaussianBlur`) before `cv2.resize`. Result from resize is not the same but with proper blur kernel size is very very similar (almost identical). Hope it'll help :)